# OpenAL Soft - Sounds cut off randomly

Tags: sound, audio, openal

I'm using OpenAL Soft 1.16.0.

Everything's running fine, but for some reason my sounds keep getting cut off at either the beginning or the end (hard to tell). It's not really noticable for music and longer sounds, but it's a big problem for anything shorter than a second, e.g. footsteps:

http://youtu.be/xrJVKjFEzYg

The sounds themselves are definitely not the issue, I've grabbed the footstep sounds from another game for testing purposes to be sure and I've tried various different sounds from different sources.

It's not the format either, the same problem occurs regardless of whether I use .mp3, .wav or .ogg files.

What could be causing this problem?

Comment: Kind of hard to tell without the code of how you use openal. Are you using multiple sources? If you just use one you might be resetting the playback.

Comment: I'm using multiple sources and the problem occurs even if I just play a single sound, once. I'll post some code later on, once I'm at home.